# I installed Maven Integration in the Eclipse but I can't create Maven POM file! Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc

I installed Maven Integration in the Eclipse and now, I want to create a POM.xml. but I don't see Maven POM file item in  new project window. why?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in Indigo with m2e 1.0.100:

File -> New -> Other... -> Maven -> Maven project

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add pom to existing Java project by:

> Right click on project>Confugure>convertToMavenProject

It will add Maven functionality to the Project.